# Can any tell me the procedure for getting twitter api-key for recon-ng?

Tags: linux, twitter, api-key

I went to this website: https://developer.twitter.com/en/application/use-case

They are asking a lot of details. So what would be the correct details to give to Twitter for recon-ng purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Tell them what your app is going to do and take your best guess at what the other items mean. You're the only one who knows the correct answers. In recent years, there's been bad behavior on social media (including Twitter) by bots and other apps. They only want to make sure that people are using the service according to their terms of use.